# How to populate power automate adaptive card with contents of Teams Message

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I am using the 'For Selected Message' to trigger a power automate flow from within a MS Teams chat, like so:

[image: Image of adaptive card editor]

The 'For Selected Message' trigger allows you to create an adaptive card to gather more information, for example:

[image]

Which then opens the designer:

[image]

The Power Flow shows me what information is available with the 'For a Selected Message' trigger:

[image]

I would like to make use of `Message Content` within the adaptive card, that is shown when the flow is run. Not a card I am returning to the user. The reason for this is that I might like to edit the message content, before I add it to a list:

[image]

[image]

How would I achieve this? There does seem to be some support for variables, but a lot of what I can find in relation to this appears to be for when a card is posted to the chat.

For example I have added `${triggerBody()?['teamsFlowRunContext']?['MessagePayload']?['Body']?['PlainText']}` as the default value of a text input, but the plain text message that triggered the flow is not visible.

Comment: I’m confused. You just inject custom values to the card if you want to show specific values that relate to content you already have on hand.

Comment: I'm confused too! How would I inject custom values? the values are available in the next steps further along the flow, but I can't seem to access the values in the initial adaptive card

Comment: I guess because the adaptive card is part of the trigger, there is no scope to define variables earlier in the flow. That said, I would expect the content associated with the message that is used by the trigger to be available for injecting as a variable

Comment: Once the card is submitted, that’s it. You have to construct a new card which can replace the old one or be added to the users feed. Also, you’ve shown us a screenshot of the designer, how about you show us some screenshots annotated with the specifics of your problem. Show us the card before, after and your flow with the JSON you want to effect.

Comment: @Skin, I have added more screenshots and tried to explain the specifics. This isn't a card that is being sent back to the chat. The flow initiator see's the card when the flow is ran as part of the the trigger for 'For a Selected Message'

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the updated info, really useful.  So what exactly is the problem because on the surface, that looks fine.  Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: There are no errors, I'm just not sure how to bring the content held within the trigger in to the adaptive card (for editing) before saving to a list

Comment: Your expression looks fine interestingly enough. Can you show the JSON that’s in the trigger AND the step result where you’re using that expression?

Comment: The expression is within the trigger. The trigger 'For Selected Message' automatically launches the adaptive card for further text input, and I'm trying to see if I can load data passed to the trigger into that card

Comment: See but this is where the confusion sets in. It’s a one way flow unless you invoke another card and that’s what I was trying to point out initially. You said … “ This isn't a card that is being sent back to the chat. The flow initiator see's the card when the flow is ran as part of the the trigger for 'For a Selected Message'” … so the use of an expression in the card will do nothing. The data flow is, user invokes card, user fills in card, PA runs with card contents, you do something with that data. That’s it …! What am I missing?!? Do you want to do further editing yourself?

Comment: are you looking for the same?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/daily-weather-sample

Comment: Thanks, both @Skin, I don't think you're missing anything, but what I'd like to know is since PA knows to generate the card with the trigger from a MS Teams msg, can the contents of the msg be used in the card, edited if needed, then PA continue with the flow?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, I'm not sure how that helps. I will check the other samples  though.

Comment: Yes, the contents can be edited but not quite as you think.  The difference with this approach and the normal adaptive card approach is that this card doesn't stay in the feed, therefore, you can't use the `Update an adaptive card in a chat or channel` operation to overwrite it.  What you'd need to do is what I suggested initially and that's create a new card and post that to yourself (or whoever) is tasked with triaging what was entered so they can change it accordingly.  Use the adaptive card designer (https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) for that and ...

Comment: ... the `Post adaptive card and wait for a response` operation to present it to a user.  From there, you can inject the data from the original card into this new card, have it sent to the relevant user, update/change the data that originally came in, submit that new card and then the process the output of it to where ever it needs to go.  I hope that makes sense.